# PHP - string not being found within mutilple files

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have some working code that was created years ago, but I now want to remove the stripos function and instead only use an exact match (without case sensitiveness). The code snippet below is what I have before I made modifications, and it works correctly.

```
<?php
$unicorn = file('unicornsites.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$aligator = file('aligatorsites.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$cat = file('catsites.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);


$srch = $_POST['search'];

$srch = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $srch);
$srch = preg_replace('#^wwww?.#', '', $srch);

if (array_filter($aligator, function($var) use ($srch) {return stripos($var,$srch)!==false;}))
    echo '<br />That site features an aligator/div>';
elseif (array_filter($unicorn, function($var) use ($srch) {return stripos($var,$srch)!==false;}))
    echo '<br />That site features a unicorn. </div>';
elseif (array_filter($cat, function($var) use ($srch) {return stripos($var,$srch)!==false;}))
    echo '<br />That site  features a cat.</div>';
else
    echo '<br />This site features no animal</div>';
 ?>
```

This isn't sufficient for my needs anymore, so I wanted to only say what animal is on the site when the address (the srch string) is an exact match as opposed to a very close match. I changed the program to remove the stripos function in an attempt to achieve this, but it would seem my logic is incorrect. The program successfully runs, but it doesn't actually seem to find the string *"stackoverflow.com"* in any text file,  despite it being in unicornsites.txt.

It's not the fault of removing http/https/www from the address as an echo confirms this. I'm sure it's a misunderstanding on my part on how I should be searching for a string within mutilple files. Can anyone re-position me in the right direction?

```
<?php
$unicorn = file('unicornsites.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$aligator = file('aligatorsites.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$cat = file('catsites.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);


$srch = $_POST['search'];

$srch = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $srch);
$srch = preg_replace('#^wwww?.#', '', $srch);

if(in_array($srch, $aligator)) {
        echo '<br />That site features an aligator/div>';
} elseif(in_array($srch, $unicorn)) {
        echo '<br />That site features a unicorn. </div>';
} elseif(in_array($srch, $cat)) {
        echo '<br />That site  features a cat.</div>';
    else
        echo $srch . '<br />This site features no animal</div>';
     ?>
```

Comment: If $srch doesn't contain new line char, I guess you need  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES flags in file()  to remove "\n" in arrays.

Comment: @progysm - I actually had FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES in there before, but it didn't change anything so I kept it out. I've added it back in for clarity though.

Comment: I've tried it with custom data in each files and in $srch and it works with two modifications in the PHP: FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES as suggested and adding a  }  before the else to make it syntax error free. It works with the string "stackoverflow.com" too.

Comment: @progysm - Oops. I mistakenly used the same piece of code on my server, but I forgot I changed some variables for anonymity reasons. Switched them back to the proper names, used FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES and added the } and it's all worked like a champ. If I could give you a "best answer", I would. Thanks, albeit asking help for something so simple was rather embarrassing.